# Python typing in a loop of customs classes,

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, type-hinting

Since Python 3.5, it's possible to use typing hints. I now face a situation where I'm not able to find the proper way to use it.

I have 2 files (FileA.py, FileB.py), where class AA is using class BB, and class BB is using class AA.

The following code is working properly :

**FileA.py**

```
from FileB import BB

class AA:

    def __init__(self):
        self.link_to_b = None

    def add_b(self, b: BB):
        self.link_to_b = b
```

**FileB.py**

```
class BB:

    def __init__(self):
        self.property_b = 42
        self.link_to_a = None

    def add_a(self, a):
        self.link_to_a = a
```

The method add_b(self, b: BB) from class AA is using the typing hints, specifying that b should be an instance of BB.

I'd like to do the same for the method add_a(self, a) from the class BB. The problem is that as soon as I am trying to import the class from the other file (the same way I did in FileA.py) I got an error message.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BB' from 'FileB'
```

If I don't import it, but try to use the typing hint like the following, I got a NameError message.

```
def add_a(self, a: AA):

NameError: name 'AA' is not defined
```

What should be the proper way to use the typing hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of options to use type hints on objects that have yet to be defined:

- Use a [forward-reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) type string: `def add_a(self, a: 'AA')`
- Use [Postponed Evaluation of Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) `from __future__ import annotations`